# How to get files list in JSON format from GIT

Tags: json, git, github

I am using the GUT API to get the files list. I am using the [GIT API Get Contents](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents)

This is the URL:

https://github.com/repos/gitster/git/contents/git

where gister is owner
git is repository
git is path

But I get error as below:

```
{
  "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Please help me how to get the files list using GIT API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the url from https://github.com/repos/gitster/git/contents/git to http://api.github.com/repos/gitster/git/contents/ as given by Github's API documentation as you have mentioned

`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://api.github.com/repos/gitster/git/contents/',
    method : 'GET',
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps for your case